# Webview is not shown in Alertdialog

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog

I have a problem showing a webview when you touch one item from Listview. The alert dialog works fine but it doesn't show anything. I tried other ways to show but always the alert dialog is empty. Does Somebody know the way to show successful?

```
final AlertDialog.Builder detailsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        lstView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

                webView = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webkit);

                webView.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.co.uk");

                detailsDialog.setView(layout);
                detailsDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                detailsDialog.create();
                detailsDialog.show();



            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of loading a `WebView` in a `Dialog`. It looks like you might be inflating yours incorrectly.

```
    final WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.co.uk");
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setView(webView)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .show();
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

Comment: I can't put `final WebView webView = new WebView(this);` inside `setOnItemClickListener` and the problem it's that I don't know how fix it the structure.

Comment: @UKAndroid Yes, you can. Change `this` to `YourClass.this` or move it outside `onItemClick`.